# Xamarin: object must implement IConvertible

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, iconvertible

I get the following Exception

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Object must implement IConvertible.'

on line 2, or any line after the start of the function.

```
public int SaveItem<T>(T item) where T : IBusinessEntity, new() {
    if (database.Table<T>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == item.ID) != null)
    {
        database.Update(item);
        return item.ID.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        return database.Insert(item);
    }
}
```

Its being called by

```
public void SaveCategory(Category c){
     db.SaveItem<Category>(c);
}
```

The Function has been used for the last 3 years without a problem but when I recently had to update some NuGet Packages (namely SQLite PCL) it stopped working. Im at my wits end.

Comment: Where have  you this error message? Where did you convert data?

Comment: On the first line of the SaveItem Function.

Comment: I see you use Generic constraint, so the Category class derived from the IBusinessEntity class?

Comment: Exactly. The businessEntity Interface has a single simple integer property

Comment: According to your description, I can not reproduce your issue, so can you provide one simple sample at github that can reproduce your issue? I will help you to test at my side.